# How to create Maven Multi Module Project in Intellij?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I am using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.1.3. I'm trying to create a maven multi module project. Project company is the parent and Project employee and Project skillset are child modules. Project employee and skillset will have packing as a WAR but Project company has packing as POM.

[image]
my project structure look like this (above), but i need my project structure to be like below image
[image]

and I could not create a class under employee and skillset. How can I create a multi module project without having src folder in parent (company)?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your presumption is correct, the top level project being `pom` packaging should have no source.

So start by removing (just delete or move elsewhere) the `src` folder from the top level (and everything under it... main, java, resources, text...)

Now, looking at your modules, they look correct. You can test they are configured properly by control-clicking them from the top pom, and they should navigate to the child pom's.

Lastly you want to set up a source structure under the child projects (which have war packaging). Manually create a folder structure under `Employee` module `src\main\java`, right click it and choose `Mark As -> Source Root`.

Do same for `SkillSet` and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

I know you got your answer. This is for those who are using updated versions.

I am using Ultimate 2019.1. I had two spring boot projects generated from Spring Initializer. I created a directory where I kept my two sub-project and the parent pom.

Then I kept the cursor on /src/main/java of each project, right-click on the Java folder and choose `Mark Directory as -> Generated Source Root`.

These solved my problem.